# Where should authentication be done: "Webserver or AppServer"?

Tags: java, authentication, webserver

Consider the following architecture that has two web-servers(for balancing) and around 10 java app servers for servlet processing.

Where do you think is the right place for doing authentication. In ApacheWebserver or custom code at one of the app servers?

If I do authentication at Webserver how should we handle custom things like OPenId?

EDIT: Also what are the implications of choosing either on Performance, Scalability and Security?

Answer (score 2):

As usual with architecture question the answer depends on many things.

- Do the web servers do anything that needs protection (like serving static content. Then you'll have to do authentication on (or before) the webserver
- are the web servers or the app servers close to maximum capacity? Try to do authentication on the side
- Can the web server handle all the authentication requirements? Or is logic/information needed that is not available on the web server (like the reputation here at SO which affects, what user may do). The requirement to support OpenId might be such a limiting factor.
- Finally note that there are not so obvious attacks which might be affected by where you do authentication. e.g. if the web server handles 404 (not found) but the app server handles authentication (401) an attacker can find out if a resource is available or not even if he doesn't gain access. Since replying will take longer if the app server needs to be accessed this information might even leak to the attacker when in both cases an identical response is returned.

Comment: How do both of them fare in terms of security and performance?

Comment: This is a little like asking: "What is faster a chair or a tomato?" Specify what exactly your authentication/authorization needs are, what your requirements are and what attack vectors you worry about, than add some thousand bucks for reading, understanding and analysing all that and someone will possibly come up with an answer. Or just accept the "It depends" given in the first sentence. :)